# Passing parameter to regex expression in PowerShell function

Tags: regex, powershell

I am having difficulties passing parameter into a function that perform Get-ADUser filtration. I believed  the second parameter $GivenName failed to parse to the '-like ' expression

```
function get-user
{
    Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$domain,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$GivenName)
    get-aduser -server $domain -Filter 'givenname -like *$GivenName* '
}
```

```
Error
Supply values for the following parameters:
domain: asia
givenname: herng
get-aduser : Error parsing query: 'givenname -like *$givenname* ' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '17'.
At line:4 char:5
+     get-aduser -server $domain -Filter 'givenname -like *$givenname*  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.G 
   etADUser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps):

> For example, if the filter expression is double-quoted, the variable should be enclosed using single quotation marks: Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$UserName'". On the contrary, if curly braces are used to enclose the filter, the variable should not be quoted at all: Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $UserName}.

So you could try `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$GivenName'"`

If you need asterisks, you can concat the string inside the function:

```
$GivenName = '*' + $GivenName + '*';
```

Comment: Thanks man..this answered my question.cheers

Comment: @ganherngyih If answer helped you, please accept it (green check mark on the left)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string literal `'givenname -like *$GivenName* '` to `Get-AdUser` so `$GivenName` is not being expanded to its value. Try using double quotes like so: `"givenname -like *$GivenName* "`.

Answer (score 0):

Is simpler as I thought. Lets not alter the variable

```
function get-user
{
    Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$domain,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$givenname)
    get-aduser -server $domain -Filter 'givenname -like $givenname'|ft
}
```

Therefore I am free to supply my parameter(normal or with regex)